# symfony, зачем аннотации

Tags: php, ооп, symfony

Всем привет, я примерно 6-7 работаю бэкенд разработчиком, всегда писал на чистом php, работаю только с какими-то библиотеками из packagist.
Начал изучать symfony, ранее на практике применял только  несколько его компонентов. 
Читая документация и смотря примеры, я замечаю, что аннотации играют достаточно серьезную роль в фреймворке, подскажите пожалуйста так ли это? С чем это связано.
На практике не сталкивался с аннотациями. И вообще зачем это нужно?
Уж больно не нравится в dock-block`ах что-то писать, определять или проверять. 
Глаза слезятся когда вижу код в комментариях, который является частью функционала.

Какие задачи они пытаются решить? И вообще как быть, я никогда не смогу это воспринять и работать с этим. Но symfony-то хочется..

И так с тяжестью переношу отсутствие generics и enumeration в php. 
у меня кризис.

Comment: Вы можете не использовать аннотации, если они вам не нравятся. Вы так же можете использовать yaml либо xml файлы

Comment: их можно заменять yaml файлами?

Comment: Если переключить документацию на версию 3.4 можно увидеть табы переключением между  аннотациями, xml, yaml, php. Не знаю почему в более новых версиях это удалили из документации, но это и дальше можно использовать, и это работает

Comment: Очень странно вы изучаете симфони если не в курсе что аннотации можно заменять на yaml/xml/php-код. @Alpha на оф сайте во всех версиях существуют переключалки между yaml/xml/php-кодом для разных настроек.

Comment: Сам недавно начал писать на symfony, сейчас идет первый проект. До этого был год Laravel, а до него - 8 лет чистого PHP. Сначала был в шоке. Потом начал привыкать. Сейчас для себя выбрал именно аннотации в классах. Они позволяют мне одним взглядом увидеть всю функциональность класса, в отличии от yaml/xml файлов, куда надо будет лезть отдельно и искать детали. В yaml держу основные настройки. Правда, от шока из-за генерируемого кода пока не совсем отошел. :) IMHO. И Вы для себя со временем выработаете удобный стиль написания. Я из-за этих аннотаций 3 года тянул с освоением symfony. :)